# T-SQL CAST only failing when within IN clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following two tables (in SQL Server 2017):

Parts

- PartCode INT
- IsActive BIT
- ...other fields...

Products

- PartCode VARCHAR(6)
- ...other fields...

In the Products table, PartCode is either a 6-digit number or alpha followed by 5 digits.  The Parts table is only concerned with those parts with 6-digit numeric part codes.

This query successfully returns the list of numeric part codes from the Products table:

```
SELECT CAST(PartCode AS INT) FROM Products WHERE ISNUMERIC(PartCode)=1
```

However, once I embed it within an IN, like this:

```
UPDATE Parts
SET IsActive=0
WHERE PartCode NOT IN (SELECT CAST(PartCode AS INT)
                       FROM Products
                       WHERE ISNUMERIC(PartCode)=1)
```

it fails with "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'K12345' to data type int."

I am aware of the odd behaviors of ISNUMERIC (unexpected values that it returns 1 for), but in this case, `SELECT ISNUMERIC('K12345')` is 0 as expected.

Since ISNUMERIC properly excluded the K12345 value on the SELECT, why did it attempt to cast it with the UPDATE?  It should have been excluded from the result set (as it was when running the SELECT by itself) and thus not need to be converted.  Why does placing the SELECT within an IN make it behave differently?

Comment: Use try_cast() or try_convert()  They will return NULL if the conversion fails

Comment: The query plan SQL Server comes up with is based on the entire query, so when you change the query you change the plan, and it doesn't always build the query in the order you might expect for various reasons... for example it might be carrying out 2 queries in parallel and only filtering once complete.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is, in truth, a terrible function; it checks to see if the value will convert to *any* of the numerical data types, which means that `'1.00'` and `'5e10'`  would both return `1`, but `CAST('1.00' AS int)` will fail.

Comment: The execution plan is applying the isnumeric predicate condition *after* it has applied the cast; there are workarounds such as using a rowgoal but the better option is as mentioned to use *try_convert* and test for nulls; the best solution is not to mix and rely on numeric types in a varchar column.

Comment: I set up a small SQL Fiddle and was not able to reproduce your error - it seemed to work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8cddf7/1/0

Comment: @BjorgP Because it's plan dependent. Different indexes, cardinality, etc, can change the plan and thus change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the obvious "fix the database", you can avoid most problems by using EXISTS().

```
UPDATE Parts
   SET IsActive=0
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
           FROM Products
          WHERE Products.PartCode = CAST(Parts.PartCode AS VARCHAR(6))
       )
```

This way you're converting an integer to a string, and it always works. It also continues to allow use of any index on `Products.PartCode`.

Answer (score -1):

Put the check in the select term:

```sql
UPDATE Parts
SET IsActive=0
WHERE PartCode NOT IN (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(PartCode)=1 THEN CAST(PartCode AS INT)
            ELSE -1
        END
    FROM Products)
```

The reason it's exploding in your version is the optimizer must be applying the `where` clause *after* evaluating the `select` list.

Comment: Be careful; even this often advertised trick with a `CASE` doesn't always guarantee the optimizer will evaluate the `WHEN` before the `THEN`, even though it does so in many more cases than with a split between a `WHERE` and a `SELECT` and forcing the query to fail becomes much harder. Even in this setup using `TRY_CAST`/`TRY_CONVERT` is always preferable just to stay on the safe side.

Comment: `CAST(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(PartCode)=1 THEN PartCode ELSE '-1' END AS INT)` isn't susceptible to this, as there is no order of execution that the scalar expression can be "mis-evaluated". It's still susceptible to other issues, such as decimals, etc.